# jQuery on hover menu-items change Main image

Tags: jquery, css, image, src

On [this site](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl) we have the main menu. 'On hover' the menu-items i want to change the 'Main-image' in the **third column.** The owner is using a plugin to built the menu. I am stuck to this structure. But i can give a CSS class name: `links1`, `links2` etc (to split up the columns) see below:

```
<div class="grid-column grid-column3 links1 ">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="imageLink ">Link 1</li>
    <li class="imageLink ">Link 2</li>
    <li class="imageLink ">Link 3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The structure for the Main-image in the third column is:

```
<div id="imageBox">
  <img class="imageChangeDefault">
</div>
```

Is it possible with jQuery `.attr('src')` to change the image in the **Image box**, and how exactly? I really hope there is a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in your case the `content` css is having the image so you shouldnt be editing the `attribute`, instead change the css like this `$('.imageChangeDefault').css('content','url(the url of the image)')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't exactly understand what you mean. How will it look like, what do i have to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i would recommend you to follow the answer which is given by `Roko C. Buljan`. only change you have to do in that is, change the code from `attr('src', thumb)` to `css('content','url('+thumb+')')`

Comment: @Cerlin Boss ok so now i have `$(".imageLink").mouseover(function () {
   var thumb = $(this).data('thumb');
   $(this).closest(".parent").find(".imageChangeDefault").css('content','url('+thumb+')');
  });` How do i connect now the right image to the right link? Do i have to make some CSS? What will be the CSS for the first link 'Babyboek' ? Thanks!

Comment: @CerlinBoss do you have any clue what to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html has to be like

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li class="imageLink ">
        <a title="Babyboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/babyboek.html" target="_self" data-bgimage="url to the image">
            <i class=""></i><span>Babyboek</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="imageLink ">
        <a title="Collegaboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/collegaboek.html" target="_self" data-bgimage="url to the image">
            <span>Collegaboek</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="imageLink ">
        <a title="Kookboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/kookboek.html" target="_self" data-bgimage="url to the image">
            <span>Kookboek</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="imageLink ">
        <a title="Liefdesboek" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/liefdesboek.html" target="_self" data-bgimage="url to the image">
            <span>Liefdesboek</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="blue ">
        <a title="Bekijk alle boeken" href="http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/boeken.html" target="_self" data-bgimage="url to the image">
            <span>Bekijk alle boeken</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have added a `data-bgimage` attribute to the `anchor` tag which  should have the corresponding background image.

Add the below script after adding the proper html

WITHOUT FADE EFFECT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.level1 li').mouseenter(function(){
        $this = jQuery(this);
        if(typeof $this.find('img').attr('src') != "undefined"){
            $this.parent().parent().parent().find('.imageChange').css('background','url('+$this.find('img').attr('src')+')').css('background-repeat','no-repeat').css('width','inherit').css('height','inherit').css('background-size','100% 100%');
        }
    });
})
```

WITH FADE EFFECT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.level1 li').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if(typeof $this.find('img').attr('src') != "undefined"){
            var imgelem = $this.parent().parent().parent().find('.imageChange');
            imgelem.hide();
            imgelem.css('background','url('+$this.find('img').attr('src')+')')
                .css('background-repeat','no-repeat')
                .css('width','inherit')
                .css('height','inherit')
                .css('background-size','100% 100%');
            imgelem.fadeIn(500)
        }
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.parent().parent().parent().find('.imageChange').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: Last question: how do i reconstruct so its only `fadeIn()` or `fadeTo()` on hover?

Comment: yes it only should fadeIn quickly on hover the menu item.. And what is that grey border around the image? Thanks a lot for your help, i really appreciate.

Comment: About the fade. I mean how will i do it so it's only fading in smoothly?

Comment: isnt it fading in smoothly now?

Comment: now there is a strange behavior. I want it on 'mouse enter' the menu item it appears (fadeIn) from opacity 0 to 100. On 'mouse leave' it just disappear without fading. Thanks!

Comment: have done a small modification to suit your need. please check the updated answer

Comment: i get crazy of that border i really don't know what it is? Can't get it away.. You? And if you hover the link and you go to the right a little its fading in again (before leave the <li>)?

Comment: i figured out a fix for the border, change the `<img class="imageChangeDefault" ></img>` to `<div class="imageChangeDefault" ></div>`

Comment: ok also i changed the class name to `imageChange`. But what about the jQuery function? I tried this: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.level1 li').mouseover(function(){
          $this = jQuery(this);
          if(typeof $this.find('imageChange').attr('src') != "undefined"){
              $this.parent().parent().parent().find('imageChange').css('background','url('+$this.find('imageChange').attr('src')+')').css('background-repeat','no-repeat').css('width','inherit').css('height','inherit').css('background-size','100% 100%');
          }
      });
  })`

Comment: what you have changed the tagname to?? `div`??

Comment: yes to `<div class="imageChange" ></div>` and now i changed in the jQuery function `img` to `div` but no result?

Comment: you don't need to add anything except this, change from  `imageChangeDefault` to `imageChange`; Will change this in answer now.

Comment: ok i got it now i had to change also `.css('width','inherit').css('height','inherit')` to `.css('width','190px').css('height','190px')` And about the fadeIn > And if you hover the link and you go to the right a little its fading in and out again (before leave the <li>)?

Comment: i have changed the event type in answer ( `mouseover` to `mouseenter`). This should solve your problem. :)

Comment: yes great and can i do something like `.mouseleave()` `imgelem.hide();` so on mouseleave hiding `<div class="imageChange" ></div>` directly. What is the best way to do this? And then we are there!! Thanks a million for all you help!!

Comment: if you hide the `image` on `mouseleave` then the image area will be empty. i dont think this will look good. i will add the code for that now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply attach to the LI element an `data-*` attribute with the src of the desired image to show:

```
<li data-thumb="thumbs/babyboek.jpg" class="imageLink ">
```

Than with jQuery:

```
$('[data-thumb]').mouseenter(function() {
   var thumb = $(this).data('thumb');
   $(this).closest(".parent").find(".imageChangeDefault").attr('src', thumb);
});
```

(P.S. didn't had the time to look further but make sure to avoid duplicate IDs `imageBox`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with jQuery.

```
// for image link...
$('.imageLink').hover(function(){
      //change image for parent...here
      $(this).parent().attr('src', 'new-image');
 }, function(){

      // do something in hover out if needed...
 });

 // for imageBox ...use this:

$('#imageBox').hover(function(){
     $(this).children(':eq(0)').attr('src', 'new-image');
}) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do i set the `'src'` they are all different file-names.. And how do i split them up in the wright columns (`links1`, `links2`, etc). I don't understand how i connect the right image with the right link? Thanks!

Comment: to connect the right image with right link ...you have to map the image with the link. try with an extra html attribute like this:
<li image-file="your-image-file" class=""></li> 
Then get this attr and set as new image...

Comment: i can't because the owner of the site is controlling the menu with a plugin. I can't simply add an extra attribute..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as you said, with jQuery.

```
.attr('src', 'imageurl.jpg');
```

But, I think is better if you have preloaded images in different menus. 
The main problem I see is that you have a class with the image url.

Here you have an ugly working example with jQuery;
http://jsfiddle.net/ft52xa5o/

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! So basically i make all different hover-functions for all the different menu-items? So i get i whole list off functions below each other? What do you mean exactly with 'you have preloaded images in different menus...' Thanks!

Comment: I meant "hard coded" 
I just meant that you have the image URL in the class. It's not a problem, but IMO it's easier if you have img src! 

If you can't change the code, only the javascript, I think you will have to change it with different functions as I said. Hope it helps!